# Can we call dealloc funcation explicitily in viewController class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know for sure that we can't but what would be exact explanation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps these may help you

[Calling dealloc in init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042934/calling-dealloc-in-init)

[[self release], [self dealloc] or [super dealloc] in init methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907311/self-release-self-dealloc-or-super-dealloc-in-init-methods)

[Difference between release and dealloc in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559295/difference-between-release-and-dealloc-in-objective-c)