# Solution for a leak in touchXML when no internet and using initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

There's a leaking CXMLDocument object shown in instruments everytime, a request to an XML is made to  a webservice AND when there's no internet connection available. Here's my code:

```
NSString *path = ... some URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: path];
CXMLDocument *itemListParser; = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];
... other stuff ...
```

If we digg deeper and trace initWithContentsOfURL call then we will find this method in "CXMLDocument.m":

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)inURL encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding options:(NSUInteger)inOptions error:(NSError **)outError
  {
  if (outError)
    *outError = NULL;

  NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:inURL options:NSUncachedRead error:outError];
  if (theData)
    {
    self = [self initWithData:theData encoding:encoding options:inOptions error:outError];
    }
  else
    {
        [self release]; //My suggested fix: We need to release an alloc'ed object because after the "self = null" it will be unable to release it. See the info below.
        self = NULL;
    }

  return(self);
}
```

It appears, if theData is nil (for example no connection) then self will be nil, and so the result of the call to TouchXML initWithContentsOfURL will be nil too. So, in my code:

```
CXMLDocument *itemListParser; = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil];
```

I'm alloc'ing a memory but init returns nil, and so itemListParser becomes nil too. So later, trying to release the parser with [itemListParser release] does nothing because release is send to nil.

I was able to fix a leak by adding "[self release]" before "self = NULL" (see the line with my comment in TouchXML initWithContentsOfURL method)

Comment: From my understanding your solution is right, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907311/self-release-self-dealloc-or-super-dealloc-in-init-methods